# Makefile: ignored pattern rule

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a C++ project that require headers files.I build some of the headers files with a python script from some files (.srv). I want my Makefile to run my script if the header is missing or srv files have changed.
I added this line to my makefile:

```
    include/services/%.h : include/srv/%.srv
        python headersFromSRV.py $<
```

When I try to build my project I get the error message:

```
 fatal error: 'include/services/robot_device_list.h' file not found
 #include "include/services/robot_device_list.h"
```

Which is logic as the file doesn't exist yet, but it doesn't invoke the rule to create it.
What is wrong with my rule ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule in itself is OK, but perhaps your problem is that the makefile doesn't know that it is a requirement.
I guess the error message is coming from your C/C++ compiler, who is building some other target. You probably need to add the robot_device_list.h as a dependency to that target, so the makefile knows he needs to build that first.
For instance

```
foo.exe: foo.o
   (your link statement)

foo.o: foo.c include/services/robot_device_list.h
   (your compile statement)
```

Comment: You're probably right. The rule to build the other target are defined in another Makefile that I don't own and include in my Makefile. I only define the list of *.cpp sources that will be needed to compile the target. Unfortunately this second Makefile only accept *.cpp files in this list and ignore others. Is there a way to add the dependency on my *.cpp for example without changing the rules to build the target ?

Comment: if your makefile is included, you can add any sorts of rules to your makefile, like the last one in the example.

Comment: I made a basic rule that depends on my header files. All my headers got created succesfully ! I had to put the rule after the include, else the main target wouldn't be build. Thanks.